# Regex - if contain word, then last char must be whitespace

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a string 'na nie' and I want to create a regex to search for it - it should also find 'na xxx nie', but not 'nanie' or 'na xxxnie'.

My code right now is:

```
/^(na)[\W]+[\W]?(nie)$/i
```

but it does not work for 'na xxxnie' - my problem is how to determine in regex: 'if there is a word inside, then last char should be whitespace'

EDIT: what about 'xxx na nie' ?

Comment: I guess this should support Unicode chars like `ż`, right? Try [`/^(na)\s+(?:(\S+)\s+)?(nie)$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/uN6rH3/1).

Comment: Does `/^(na)\W+(?:.+\W])?(nie)$/i` work?

Comment: `\s` will Match a whitespace.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please be specific which strings you want your regex to return `true` (as in "it matches") and which strings it should return `false` for (no match). We don't know what you mean by "EDIT: what about 'xxx na nie'" as you did not specify if that is a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
/^(na)\s+([^\s]*\s+)?(nie)$/i
```

Altered for the question edit:

```
/^[^\s]*\s?(na)\s+[^\s]*\s?(nie)$/i
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/eE5eJ4/1)

Comment: This will also match `na xxx yyy zzz nie`

Comment: why does my version does not work ? ''/\s?(na)\s+(.*\s)?(nie)/i''

Comment: and Your answer is not wroking - cause it matches f.e. 'xxxna nie' (shouldnt)

Comment: I have altered again. Try now.

Comment: ' xxx na  nie' not working - please tell my why my code '\s?' before '(na)' does not work ?

Comment: `\s?` before `(na)` means between 0 and 1 whitespace characters. This means that all that is accounted for is an optional whitespace character, not any sort of word. If you use https://regex101.com, it will give you a breakdown of what each part of your regex will do and allow you to test it.

Comment: yeah I know, but why does my code '/\s?(na)\s+(.*\s)?(nie)/i' is not working ?

Comment: When you use `(.\s)`, the `.` also includes whitespace characters, which means you can have multiple words between na and nie which is why I have used `[^\s]` to specify any non whitespace character. You should have used `s+` in that place to account for one or more whitespace characters. Finally, you need to use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end to assert the start and end of the string to stop matches like xxxna nie.